# How to assign values to the symbols in a parametrized Cirq circuit without running it?

Tags: programming, cirq

Is there a way to use a ParamResolver or Sweep to assign values to the symbols in a parameterized Cirq circuit without running it?

For example, something like:

```
#set up parameterized circuit
simulator = cirq.Simulator()
circuit = cirq.Circuit()
alpha = sympy.Symbol('alpha')
beta = sympy.Symbol('beta')
circuit.append(one_step(alpha, beta))
circuit.append(cirq.measure(*qubits, key='x'))
sweep = (cirq.Linspace(key='alpha', start=0.1, stop=0.9, length=5)
         * cirq.Linspace(key='beta', start=0.1, stop=0.9, length=5))
for param_resolver in study.to_resolvers(sweep):
     #resolve parameters
     *line that resolves the symbolic parameters in circuit using param_resolver*
     #run measurement simulations 
     measurements = simulator.run(circuit=circuit, repetitions=100)
```

Instead of:

```
#set up parametrized circuit
simulator = cirq.Simulator()
circuit = cirq.Circuit()
alpha = sympy.Symbol('alpha')
beta = sympy.Symbol('beta')
circuit.append(one_step(alpha, beta))
circuit.append(cirq.measure(*qubits, key='x'))
sweep = (cirq.Linspace(key='alpha', start=0.1, stop=0.9, length=5)
         * cirq.Linspace(key='beta', start=0.1, stop=0.9, length=5))
for param_resolver in study.to_resolvers(sweep):
     #resolve parameters and run measurement simulations in one step
     measurements = simulator.run(circuit=circuit, param_resolver=param_resolver, repetitions=100)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `cirq.resolve_parameters(object, resolver)`, which returns the object after the parameters have been resolved. For example:

```
import cirq
import sympy

q = cirq.LineQubit(0)
s = sympy.Symbol('s')

symbol_op = cirq.X(q)**s
resolved_op = cirq.resolve_parameters(symbol_op, {s: 0.25})
print(resolved_op)
# X**0.25(0)

symbol_circuit = cirq.Circuit(symbol_op, cirq.measure(q))
resolved_circuit = cirq.resolve_parameters(symbol_circuit, {s: 0.5})
print(resolved_circuit)
# 0: ───X^0.5───M───
```